# Blender rendering quality pixelated

Tags: rendering

I've slowly been getting better at blender but one thing that annoys me a lot is that when i press F12 to render my scene, well, it's all pixelated. 
Examles:

So this here is something i was testing out, and this is when i press Shift+Z

[image: Picture of my test, fine, no pixelation.]

So that's fine and all but then i go to F12 and i get this:
[image: Using F12, pixelated]

Now, i have read other peoples posts, and they call say "duplicate" and they all have answers, now honestly it annoys me that none of them have a good answer that actually would aid this. I've read all the things i could find, and some of the "Similar questions" and some people have the same problem as me, but i doubt there is nothing i can do?

TL;DR Want to make my renders not pixelated so i can make the low-poly scenes i've been making better. So i can actually zoom in without seeing pixels.

Comment: true. Do you know all the questions/answers ?

Comment: If Bithur's suggestion doesn't do it for ya(it most likely will), then take a screenshot of your rendering-settings (same panel as in Bithur's answer)

Comment: @NaioaiStudios What he suggested seems to work. Thanks (edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like a low res zoomed image. check your render resolution, X, Y and %. a 1000x1000 render at 25% gives a 250x250 image. Aspect ratio has to be 1.

[image]

Comment: It currently looks like this for me: http://puu.sh/g75Qa/be699fbaa9.png sort of the same as yours. I just have a few less buttons but i think that is a versions thing. Anyway, if i was to export the image (i don't know how though) would it possibly be not pixelated?

Comment: Well, i tried making the 50% at 100% it seems to be fine now as long as i don't zoom in, i guess i can live with that. So i suppose you helped. I got a clearer idea of things in this one that i have not seen in other posts. So, thanks. Edit: It does seem it only fixes it if i put the display mode in "new window" Odd, all the other ones seem pixel-ish, i'll keep it in new window then.

Comment: if you want a bigger size, zoomable, you can use 200% (or more)

Comment: I put it at 150% because 200% seems to lag. Thanks.

Comment: the image you linked has a 645×517 resolution. that's not 50% of 1920x1080 so i think you resized it. check you camera distance too

Comment: Is the Final Resolution indication on the screenshot a new feature or something?

Comment: Well, possibly, but it works now anyway.

Comment: @LeonCheung Not sure, i don't have it either, but there may be newer versions of my blender.