# Environment texture having very low resolution in reflections

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am using a 3600x1800 environment texture to cast reflections on a completely reflective sphere, but all the reflections show up in very low resolution. If I turn on "Rendered Viewport Shading" and pan around I can see the background as having the correct high resolution.

What do I need to do to get the reflections to show properly?

[image: Weirdly reflected environment texture]

**Update:** after both increasing the resolution and turning on smooth shading on the sphere, as was suggested in the linked answer and comments, I was able to get the desired result.

[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36274/reflection-is-quad-dependent-and-looks-non-realistic/36280#36280

Comment: also make sure you are rendering at 100% resolution http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26105/blender-rendering-quality-pixelated

Comment: Is your sphere set to smooth shading?